# Best Way to Determine If Binary Number Pattern Fits in Larger Binary Number

Tags: bitmap, binary, pattern-matching

I have been doing some research, and even took a look at bitwise operations, but I am wondering if anyone could offer their opinion on the best way to determine if a binary number pattern is matched anywhere within a larger binary number. Say, for example, the following:

I have the following: 001011
and need to see if the exact pattern is matched anywhere within: 010100101100

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: `bool found = "010100101100".Contains("001011");` not the fastest, but, probably, the simplest way

Comment: Very clevel @DmitryBychenko. Thanks!

Comment: Please choose an answer

Answer (score 0):

There're several ways. Which is the *best* - it's you to decide. Some *C#* examples: probably, the simplest one: just use `string` for patterns

```
bool found = "010100101100".Contains("001011");
```

bitwise: if you have to work with integers

```
private static bool Search(int toFind, 
                           int source, 
                           int toFindLength, 
                           int sourceLength = 32) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= sourceLength - toFindLength; ++i)
    if (((source >> i) & toFind) == toFind) 
      return true;

  return false;
}

...

string stSource = "010100101100";
string stToFind = "001011";

int source = Convert.ToInt32(stSource, 2);
int toFind = Convert.ToInt32(stToFind, 2);

bool found = Search(toFind, source, stToFind.Length, stSource.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this python based bit-wise solution. It assumes a 32-bit integer.

```
import math
x = int("010100101100",2)
y = int("1011",2)

highest1x = int(math.log(x,2))
highest1y = int(math.log(y,2))
mask = int(math.pow(2,highest1y+1)-1)

for i in range(0,int(32 - highest1x)):
    z = y ^ x
    if ( z & mask == 0):
            print "found"
    y = y << 1
    mask = mask << 1
```

The main idea is that XOR between two identical bit patterns will produce 0.

So we keep shifting the small bit pattern and the mask along the big one, XOR every time,, and then AND the result of the XOR with the mask to isolate the bits that we are interested in. If they are 0, then there was a match at that point in the string.